# Parse server with ElastiCache redis server and password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, parse-server, amazon-elasticache

I have set up a working Parse server on Elastic Beanstalk. I have added an AWS ElasticCache Redis server to use for caching but I can't get the connection to work when using a password, only without. In my Parse server index.js file where I create the new Parse server I connect with Redis like this:

```
// Redis cache server
var RedisCacheAdapter = require('parse-server').RedisCacheAdapter;
var redisurl='rediss://:'+process.env.REDIS_PASS+'@'+process.env.REDIS_URL
var redisOptions = {url: redisurl};
var redisCache = new RedisCacheAdapter(redisOptions);
```

Where my URL looks like `REDIS_URL=clustercfg.xxxx.xxxx.use1.cache.amazonaws.com`

I have tried both `redis://` and `rediss://`. I understand that the RedisCacheAdapter takes only one option - the URL. I thought I could add in the password directly in the link but it does not seem like the adapter parses into password and URL but just expects the URL.

My question is am I doing something wrong here or is there another way to use a password? If it is not possible to use the password I wonder what the reason is (is it because ElastiCache is hidden from the internet and only seen by the server on EC2)?

**Update:**
Base on comments from @MarkB I tested a few different settings for ElastiCache with my code above modified to also use a password.

```
var redisOptions = {url: redisurl, password: process.env.REDIS_PASS};
```

1. Running ElastiCache with cluster mode, encryption at rest, encryption in transit, and Redis password fails.
2. Running ElastiCache with encryption at rest, encryption in transit and Redis password fails.
3. Running ElastiCache with encryption at rest, and encryption in transit, no password fails.
4. Running ElastiCache **without** encryption at rest, encryption in transit and no password succeeds.

Seems to me that using encryption at rest and in transit when connecting from Parse server causes a problem I am not sure how to fix. As @MarkB mentioned, the connection between [Parse server (EC2) and ElastiCache](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-elasticache-docs/blob/master/doc_source/GettingStarted.AuthorizeAccess.md#GettingStarted.AuthorizeAccess.VPC) is restricted to VPC so I am OK with not having the security options, but still, it would be nice.

Comment: Some relevant answers here - https://serverfault.com/questions/837283/how-to-secure-redis-cluster-on-aws-elasticache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Parse Server documentation [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/), the `redisOptions` will be passed directly to the redis client documented [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#rediscreateclient) which supports a `password` field. I believe that's how you need to be specifying a password instead of specifying it in the URL.

Also note it says if you are using a Redis Client version <2.5 you need to specify `auth_pass` instead of `password`.

As you mentioned, with ElastiCache being restricted to your VPC many people consider that secure enough without adding password authentication, unless that is required for something like PCI or HIPAA compliance reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - very helpful. I have updated my question with some more experiments I did today. If you have any further comments I would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think encryption at rest is relevant at all. That would be entirely a server-side thing between the Redis/ElastiCache server and the backing EBS volumes. It wouldn't be exposed to any Redis clients at all. It sounds like encryption in transit is the issue here. Did you look at the `tls` options for the Redis client? It looks like you need to pass something like `tls: {host: hostname, port: port}`. You might have to experiment with those TLS settings a bit.

Comment: Thank you - Ill look into the TLS settings.